# App.config path not correctly interpreted by ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, dll, app-config

I'm working on a very old project (2000) in VB6 which was "modernized" and upgraded to VB.NET 3.5.
I've centralized every old INI configuration file into one MainApp.config, which is referenced by the app.config of every component.

There's an VB ASP.NET website in the solution, which uses DLL components, which are looking into app.config for parameters like, say, error log directory, etc.

I've deployed the site on my dev. server (Windows 2008 Server w/ IIS 7.0) into the `D:\WebSite\` directory.

Problem: When running the site, an error occurs.
A DLL is looking into app.config for the parameter `RepertoireErreur` which has the value `.\Erreurs\`

Instead of returning

`D:\WebSite\Erreurs\`

it returns

`c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\.\Erreurs\`

which doesn't contain the `Erreurs` directory. Boom. Error.

Does anyone have ever encountered the same problem ?
Is there a solution ?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you reading this file? Some sample code? In an ASP.NET application there's only a web.config file that's automatically read, every other config file should be opened manually.

Comment: Sorry, I meant web.config, not app.config.

Concerning reading the Web.config, here's how :
fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RepertoireErreur")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, That's weird:
Everything is finally working.
The DLL gets the correct path to write in.
I don't get it, but it suddenly works.
I guess I'll never know why ! :P
Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If the web.config contains a key with the value .\Erreurs\, then that is what it will return, i.e. the string ".\Erreurs\".  Your problem probably lies with whatever you are doing with the parameter.  The value you say it returns looks like the directory of the iis executable file with your value appended on.  Please post code to show what your dll is doing with the value it retreives from the config.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) for how to determine the local physical path of the website.